# Как увеличить максимальное кол-во tcp-соединений используя webclient?

Tags: c#, .net, http, асинхронность, httpclient

Мне нужно отправлять большое кол-во http-запросов параллельно (десятки тысяч в минуту)
Пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью асинхронных методов webclient.
Я установил значение  "System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit=10000"
Все работает довольно быстро, но во время выполнения запросов, netstat показывает, что открыто всего ~400 tcp соединений, соответственно, что-то ограничивает максимальное число соединений?
Вопрос, можно ли как-то увеличить максимальное количество одновременных соединений, используя webclient, или возможно мне стоит выбрать другую библиотеку для моей задачи?

Comment: `WebClient` устарел, об этом сказано в документации. Используйте `HttpClient`, и внимательно прочитайте все рекомендации по его использованию, особенно "Клиент должен быть создан один раз, на все время работы приложения".

Comment: Благодарю за совет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала используйте .NET 6 и новее, работать будет еще быстрее.

`ServicePointManager` работает только для устаревшего `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebRequestHandler` который устарел вместе со .NET Framework 4.x, а в .NET Core и выше `WebClient` под капотом использует `HttpClient`, а тот в свою очередь - `SocketsHttpHandler`.

1. Для новой разработки использовать сразу асинхронный `HttpClient` напрямую
2. Его соединениями тонко можно управлять передав ему в конструктор экземпляр настроенного [`SocketsHttpHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler).

При обращении к одному и тому же хосту лучше использовать HTTP/2 и одно единственное соединение. За счет особенностей протокола через одно соединение мультиплексируется большое число запросов. Для HTTP/1.1 можно регулировать количество одновременных подключений к одному и тому же серверу через [`SocketsHttpHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.maxconnectionsperserver). Количество одновременных подключений к разным хостам не ограничено.

`HttpClientHandler` создаст [правильный handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient#transports) для текущей платформы. В новых версиях .NET это будет `SocketsHttpHandler`, можно использовать конструктор `SocketsHttpHandler` явно, если требуется.

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All })
{
    DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
};
```

Используйте один и тот же `client` для всех запросов. Этого хватает для большинства приложений. Плюс ко всему если запросы идут к одному и тому же серверу, то открытое соединение будет переиспользоваться. А для HTTP/2 оно будет вообще одно, и так и должно быть, это никак не режет производительность, а наоборот повышает.

Для более сложных и тонко настраиваемых случаев с высоконагруженной работой рекомендуется использовать [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory).